# Split mixed type DataFrame into two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm munging a report I loaded into a DataFrame. The report's SKU column has mixed datatypes. I want to split the column into two new columns (SUBTOTAL and SKU) based on cell data type (str, int).

Following the example from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660662/343215) I get a boolean column. Ok

```
df['SUBTOTAL'] = df['SKU'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))

    SKU                     AMOUNT       SUBTOTAL
7   4410                    1            False
8   4200                    5            False
9   total                   6            True
11  4250                    0            False
12  4255                    0            False
```

I'm doing this in a Jupyter Notebook. Here's the thing that's driving me crazy. If I *first* call the above line, and *wrap the code* with `df[]`, and *rerun* that cell, I get what I want.

```
df['SUBTOTAL'] = df[df['SKU'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]

    SKU                     AMOUNT       SUBTOTAL
7   4410                    1            NaN
8   4200                    5            NaN
9   total                   6            total
11  4250                    0            NaN
12  4255                    0            NaN
```

But when I **Restart and Run All** I get a **Key Error**.

I have to run practically the same line twice,

```
df['SUBTOTAL'] = df['SKU'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
df['SUBTOTAL'] = df[df['SKU'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

How do I split mixed type DataFrame into two columns?

The end result should be,

```
    SKU                     AMOUNT       SUBTOTAL 
7   4410                    1            NaN
8   4200                    5            NaN
9   NaN                     6            total
11  4250                    0            NaN
12  4255                    0            NaN
```

Or I could add a new SKUb column and drop, rename, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for strings, checking for numeric data may be a better idea. You can use the optimised `pd.to_numeric` + `pd.Series.isnull` rather than `apply` + `lambda`:

```
s = df['SKU'].copy()  # make copy for later
df['SKU'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SKU'], errors='coerce')  # gives nan for non-numeric data
df['SUBTOTAL'] = np.where(df['SKU'].isnull(), s, np.nan)
```

Currently, your code is unclear. You are attempting to assign a dataframe to a series, since `df['SUBTOTAL']` is a series, but `df[df['SKU'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]` is a dataframe. This isn't recommended.

Comment: _You are attempting to assign a dataframe to a series_. I see what you mean.

Comment: This works, `np.where(df2['ACCOUNT'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), col, np.nan)`;

Comment: @xtian, Yup that'll work too. But `apply` + `lambda` is just a thinly veiled inefficient loop. The main benefit of Pandas / NumPy is vectorised operations, which is why I suggest `pd.to_numeric` + `isnull`.

Comment: The input data is not normal. The values are mixed, but not insignificant, so you can't replace null values.